# How do I gzip compress a string in Python?

Tags: python, compression, gzip

How do I gzip compress a string in Python?

[`gzip.GzipFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) exists, but that's for file objects - what about with plain strings?

Comment: @KevinDTimm, that docu only mentions `StringIO` but does not really explain how to do it.  So asking that question here is completely valid, IMHO.  Some more trials before asking and telling us about them would have been nice, though.

Comment: @Alfe - the question was closed 4 years ago for much the same reason as my comment - the OP made no effort to search first.

Comment: Of course you are right, @KevinDTimm.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: This question is the top hit in google now for `gzip string in python` and is very reasonable IMO.  It should be re-opened.

Comment: As above, this question is the top result in a google search, and one of the answers is correct - it really seems as though it shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 168):

If you want to produce a complete [`gzip`](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html)-compatible binary string, with the header etc, you could use [`gzip.GzipFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) together with [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html):

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO  # Python 2.7
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO  # Python 3.x
import gzip
out = StringIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
  f.write("This is mike number one, isn't this a lot of fun?")
out.getvalue()

# returns '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xbd\xbe\xe8N\x02\xff\x0b\xc9\xc8,V\x00\xa2\xdc\xcc\xecT\x85\xbc\xd2\xdc\xa4\xd4"\x85\xfc\xbcT\x1d\xa0X\x9ez\x89B\tH:Q!\'\xbfD!?M!\xad4\xcf\x1e\x00w\xd4\xea\xf41\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: The opposite of this is: `def gunzip_text(text):
    infile = StringIO.StringIO()
    infile.write(text)
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=infile, mode="r") as f:
        f.rewind()
        f.read()
    return out.getvalue()

Comment: @fastmultiplication: or shorter: `f = gzip.GzipFile(StringIO.StringIO(text)); result = f.read(); f.close(); return result`

Comment: Unfortunately, the question has been close, so I can't make a new answer, but [here](https://gist.github.com/Garrett-R/dc6f08fc1eab63f94d2cbb89cb61c33d) is how to do this in Python 3.

Comment: Probably unrelated, is compressing in memory first faster(using local disk)?

Comment: In Python 3: `import zlib; my_string = "hello world"; my_bytes = zlib.compress(my_string.encode('utf-8')); my_hex = my_bytes.hex(); my_bytes2 = bytes.fromhex(my_hex); my_string2 = zlib.decompress(my_bytes); assert my_string == my_string2;`

Comment: copying and pasting this into 3.7 iPython fails with `TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'`

Answer (score 73):

The easiest way is the `zlib` [encoding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings):

```
compressed_value = s.encode("zlib")
```

Then you decompress it with:

```
plain_string_again = compressed_value.decode("zlib")
```

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, `s` is a Python 2.x object of type `str`.

Comment: See [Standard Encodings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for where he got that (scroll down to __"codecs"__).  Also available: `s.encode('rot13')`, `s.encode( 'base64' )`

Comment: Note that this method is incompatible with the gzip command-line utility in that gzip includes a header and checksum, while this mechanism simply compresses the content.

Comment: I know this is old but you line of code for decompressing should be:

`plain_string_again = compressed_value.decode("zlib")`

Comment: @minillinim: Yes, someone added this slightly wrong code to my answer.  Feel free to fix it  -- it doesn't matter it's old.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg: Python 3 is stricter about the distinction between Unicode strings (type `str` in Python 3) and byte strings (type `bytes`).  `str` objects have an `encode()` method that returns a `bytes` object, and `bytes` objects have a `decode()` method that returns a `str`.  The `zlib` codec is special in that it converts from `bytes` to `bytes`, so it doesn't fit into this structure.  You can use `codecs.encode(b, "zlib")` and `codecs.decode(b, "slib")` for a `bytes` object `b` instead.

Comment: How can I direct it into a file?

Comment: Beware. This answer is wrong. It does _not_ compress to the gzip format, as asked in the question.

Answer (score 49):

Python3 version of Sven Marnach's 2011 answer:

```
import gzip
exampleString = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijmortenpunnerudengelstadrocksklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv123'
compressed_value = gzip.compress(bytes(exampleString, 'utf-8'))
plain_string_again = gzip.decompress(compressed_value).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: In Python 3 `zlib` is still used, `gzip` actually uses `zlib`, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#module-gzip

Comment: My original answer was using zlib. Changed to gzip because that was the original question. You can easily replace from gzip to to zlib (search-and-replace) in my example, and it will work.

Comment: `gzip.decompress` returns bytes, so call `plain_string_again.decode('utf-8')` to get a str object

Comment: _Unlike_ Sven Marnach's answer, this answer is correct, in that it produces the gzip format.

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to compress a Pandas dataframe in JSON format:

Tested with Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.23

```
import sys
import zlib, lzma, bz2
import math

def convert_size(size_bytes):
    if size_bytes == 0:
        return "0B"
    size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
    i = int(math.floor(math.log(size_bytes, 1024)))
    p = math.pow(1024, i)
    s = round(size_bytes / p, 2)
    return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])

dataframe = pd.read_csv('...') # your CSV file
dataframe_json = dataframe.to_json(orient='split')
data = dataframe_json.encode()
compressed_data = bz2.compress(data)
decompressed_data = bz2.decompress(compressed_data).decode()
dataframe_aux = pd.read_json(decompressed_data, orient='split')

#Original data size:  10982455 10.47 MB
#Encoded data size:  10982439 10.47 MB
#Compressed data size:  1276457 1.22 MB (lzma, slow), 2087131 1.99 MB (zlib, fast), 1410908 1.35 MB (bz2, fast)
#Decompressed data size:  10982455 10.47 MB
print('Original data size: ', sys.getsizeof(dataframe_json), convert_size(sys.getsizeof(dataframe_json)))
print('Encoded data size: ', sys.getsizeof(data), convert_size(sys.getsizeof(data)))
print('Compressed data size: ', sys.getsizeof(compressed_data), convert_size(sys.getsizeof(compressed_data)))
print('Decompressed data size: ', sys.getsizeof(decompressed_data), convert_size(sys.getsizeof(decompressed_data)))

print(dataframe.head())
print(dataframe_aux.head())
```

Answer (score 2):

Martin Thoma's answer almost worked: I had to use BytesIO as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903409/typeerror-string-argument-expected-got-bytes#62903572).

```py
from io import BytesIO # Python 3.x, haven't tested 2.7
import gzip
out = BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
  f.write("This is mike number one, isn't this a lot of fun?")
out.getvalue()
```

The original code produced a *TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'*

Answer (score -4):

```
s = "a long string of characters"

g = gzip.open('gzipfilename.gz', 'w', 5) # ('filename', 'read/write mode', compression level)
g.write(s)
g.close()
```

Comment: I guess the question was about compressing a string in memory without having to write it to disk in the process.  Otherwise your answer is totally correct.