# Python, write in memory zip to file

Tags: python, zip, stringio

How do I write an in memory zipfile to a file?

```
# Create in memory zip and add files
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(), mode='w',compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zf.writestr('file1.txt', "hi")
zf.writestr('file2.txt', "hi")

# Need to write it out
f = file("C:/path/my_zip.zip", "w")
f.write(zf)  # what to do here? Also tried f.write(zf.read())

f.close()
zf.close()
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`StringIO.getvalue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO.getvalue) return content of `StringIO`:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> f.write('asdf')
>>> f.getvalue()
'asdf'
```

Alternatively, you can change position of the file using `seek`:

```
>>> f.read()
''
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> f.read()
'asdf'
```

Try following:

```
mf = StringIO.StringIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(mf, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zf.writestr('file1.txt', "hi")
    zf.writestr('file2.txt', "hi")

with open("C:/path/my_zip.zip", "wb") as f: # use `wb` mode
    f.write(mf.getvalue())
```

---

Comment: That gives me "ZipFile instance has no attribute 'getvalue'"

Comment: @user984003, Are you run this code in Windows? Then, you have to use `wb` mode. I updated the code.

Comment: @user984003, In my ubuntu box, it works perfectly. http://i.imgur.com/MiT3UAX.png

Answer (score 19):

Modify falsetru's answer for python3

1) use `io.StringIO` instead of `StringIO.StringIO`

[StringIO in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3)

2) use `b"abc"` instead of `"abc"` , or

[python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)

3) encode to binary string `str.encode(s, "utf-8")`

[Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

```
import zipfile
import io
mf = io.BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(mf, mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:

    zf.writestr('file1.txt', b"hi")

    zf.writestr('file2.txt', str.encode("hi"))
    zf.writestr('file3.txt', str.encode("hi",'utf-8'))


with open("a.txt.zip", "wb") as f: # use `wb` mode
    f.write(mf.getvalue())
```

This should also work for gzip: [How do I gzip compress a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506897/how-do-i-gzip-compress-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Python would be such a nice language if they would not have messed up so much with the versions. There should be a way to detect Py3-valid answers...

Answer (score 1):

```
  with ZipFile(read_file, 'r') as zipread:
        with ZipFile(file_write_buffer, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipwrite:
            for item in zipread.infolist():
                # Copy all ZipInfo attributes for each file since defaults are not preseved
                dest.CRC = item.CRC
                dest.date_time = item.date_time
                dest.create_system = item.create_system
                dest.compress_type = item.compress_type
                dest.external_attr = item.external_attr
                dest.compress_size = item.compress_size
                dest.file_size = item.file_size
                dest.header_offset = item.header_offset
```

In the case where the zip file reads corrupted and you notice missing symlinks or corrupted files with wrong timestamps, it could be the fact that the file properties are not getting copied over.

The above code snippet is how I solved the problem.

Comment: Your code does not seem to do anything with `dest`. Are you missing something like `zipwrite.write(dest)` ?