# Compress Python Object in Memory

Tags: python, compression

Most tutorials on compressing a file in Python involve immediately writing that file to disk with no intervening compressed python object. I want to know how to pickle and then compress a python object in memory without ever writing to or reading from disk.

Comment: You can't compress an object, AFAIK. You *can* compress the *representation* of an object (serialized, for instance). The most obvious representation would be a string, so you may want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506897/how-do-i-gzip-compress-a-string-in-python/8513981#8513981)

Comment: Ok, so how do I pickle and then compress the representation in memory?

Comment: Compression with what compression technique? There are multiple to choose from.

Comment: Just [pickle to a string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) then compress the string (see my previous link)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use this to save memory in one place:

```
import cPickle
import zlib

# Compress:
compressed = zlib.compress(cPickle.dumps(obj))

# Get it back:
obj = cPickle.loads(zlib.decompress(compressed))
```

If `obj` has references to a number of small objects, this can reduce the amount of memory used by a lot.  A lot of small objects in Python add up because of per-object memory overhead as well as memory fragmentation.

Comment: In python 3, we need pickle as there is no cPickle.

Answer (score 11):

Batteries included.

```
>>> zlib.compress(pickle.dumps([42]))
'x\x9c\xd3\xc8)0\xe0\xf241\xe2J\xd4\x03\x00\x10A\x02\x87'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
bz2.compress(pickle.dumps(some_object))
```