# How to gzip a bytearray in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, gzip, python-requests

I have binary data inside a bytearray that I would like to gzip first and then post via requests. I found out how to gzip a file but couldn't find it out for a bytearray. So, how can I gzip a bytearray via Python?

Comment: The ugly way: save it in a file :P. But maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506897/how-do-i-gzip-compress-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at the `zlib`-module of Python.

**Python 3:** [`zlib`-module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zlib.html)

A short example:

```
import zlib
compressed_data = zlib.compress(my_bytearray)
```

You can decompress the data again by:

```
decompressed_byte_data = zlib.decompress(compressed_data)
```

---

**Python 2:** [`zlib`-module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.compress)

A short example:

```
import zlib
compressed_data = zlib.compress(my_string)
```

You can decompress the data again by:

```
decompressed_string = zlib.decompress(compressed_data)
```

As you can see, Python 3 uses bytearrays while Python 2 uses strings.

Comment: For me it wanted a string, instead of bytearray..
`compressedData  = zlib.compress(mystring)`

Comment: @mgear That's because you are using Python 2 which expects an input string - in Python 3, the function expects an bytearray... I've added this to my answer.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507012/8046487: "Note that this method is incompatible with the gzip command-line utility in that gzip includes a header and checksum, while this mechanism simply compresses the content." ; "If you want to produce a complete gzip-compatible binary string, with the header etc, you could use gzip.GzipFile together with StringIO"

Answer (score 1):

In case the bytearray is not too large to be stored in memory more than once and known as `b`, you can just:

```
b_gz = str(b).encode('zlib')
```

If you need to do deocding first, have a look at the `decode()` method of the bytearray.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct? If you call `str()` on a bytearray you get something like `"bytearray(b'test')"` - but he want's to compress the bytearray and not some string describing the bytearray (I think this could also result in a loss of data in some special circumstances?).

Comment: I just see that the code works in Python 2 only. In Python 3 there have been some changes in that area.

Comment: Ok, that's what I've thought (I'm mainly working with Python 3). You might put a note in your post for people not reading the comments on the "first try".

Answer (score 1):

The zlib module of Python Standard Library should meet your requirements :

```
>>> import zlib
>>> a = b'abcdefghijklmn' * 10
>>> ca = zlib.compress(a)
>>> len(a)
140
>>> len(ca)
25
>>> b = zlib.decompress(ca)
>>> b == a
True
>>> b
b'abcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmn'
```

This is the output under Python3.4, but it works same under Python 2.7 -

Answer (score 1):

```
import zlib 
import binascii


def compress_packet(packet):
    return zlib.compress(buffer(packet),1)

def decompress_packet(compressed_packet):
    return zlib.decompress(compressed_packet)

def demo_zlib() :

    packet1 = bytearray()
    packet1.append(0x41)
    packet1.append(0x42)
    packet1.append(0x43)
    packet1.append(0x44)

    print "before compression: packet:{0}".format(binascii.hexlify(packet1))
    cpacket1 = compress_packet(packet1)
    print "after compression: packet:{0}".format(binascii.hexlify(cpacket1))

    print "before decompression: packet:{0}".format(binascii.hexlify(cpacket1))
    dpacket1 = decompress_packet(buffer(cpacket1))
    print "after decompression: packet:{0}".format(binascii.hexlify(dpacket1))


def main() :
    demo_zlib() 

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

This should do. The zlib requires access to bytearray content, use buffer() for that.